# URL Scheme for Swarm

Tags: ios, foursquare

How to open the URL Scheme of swarm applications for checkins in some place?

I just want to use swarm app in my application.

Answer (score 5):

To link to swarm:

```
swarm:
```

To link to checkin screen of swarm app:

```
swarm://checkins/add
```

To link to checkin to specific location (update location hash to suit):

```
swarm://checkins/add?venueId=560d1028498eee2df9f982f0
```

Comment: Thanks, the direct venue/location checkin link worked for me!

Comment: Do you have a documentation link for these?

Comment: Pieced together from various places that I can't recall all of. Certainly no official docs. Also, remember that all swarm stuff used to simply be foursquare stuff... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foursquare-api/cSyC-tCN2I4

Answer (score 0):

All url scheme provided by foursquare/swarm are on [this page](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#iphone). The scheme url that you need is not available in the list, you should try with urls like *swarm://checkins/lat=5&lon=5* but without probably never get there.

Another option is to use Foursquare's API to send checkins from your app.

Comment: I want to find a URL scheme that will make Checkins on swarm

Comment: I very likely that the URL does not exist, it depends if the developers of Swarm have planned it.

Answer (score 0):

To prepare a checkin to a specific venue using its id:

```
NSString *venueID = @"my_lovely_venue_id";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"swarm://"]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"swarm://checkins/add?venueId=" stringByAppendingString:venueID]]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://"];
    //here write your destination application name
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
        {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    }
```

Comment: @goti , can you please explain in brief what you want ?

Comment: I want to learn URL scheme which will open a correct venue in swarm